# what's the point of auto_ptr & unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I just can't understand the meaning of unique_ptr or auto_ptr, as we all know, once the parameter gets out of its scope, we won't get memory leaks. However, is it a better idea if I create the parameter on the stack rather on the heap. I don't see its advantage over normal parameters. If we really need to create parameters on the heap, then we must use `new` operator, right?

Here is a little code snippet:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        cout << "Base::()" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        cout << "~Base()" << endl;
    }

    virtual void iPhone()
    {
        cout << "I'm iPhone5s" << endl;
    }
};

class Derive : public Base
{
public:

    Derive()
    {
        cout << "Derive()" << endl;
    }

    virtual void iPhone()
    {
        cout << "I'm iPhone 6" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Derive()
    {
        cout << "~Derive()" << endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
  {

      auto_ptr<Base> ptr(new Derive());//a foolish idea to do so?
      ptr->iPhone();

      Derive d;//isn't it better?
      Base* base = &d;
      base->iPhone();
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, prefer automatic variables whenever possible. However, you can't deny that sometimes it's necessary to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: If you have to create dynamic amount of resources, or pass around such resources, it's good to have unique_ptr to ensure leak prevention. Forget about auto_ptr, it's legacy only.

Comment: yes you can always use variables on the stack, but if you need a huge chunk and you put on stack, it may overflow (see the name of this website). heap can store more data without overflow

Comment: What would you do if you wanted a vector of phones of different types?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` also makes for a good class member, and obviously there you can't use the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can help to look at [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in the form of ownership instead of as pointers: `std::unique_ptr` when something can only have one owner at a time, and `std::shared_pointer` when something can be shared.

Note that since C++11 (which introduced the other smart pointers) [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) has been deprecated.

Comment: +1 Ownership relations are the real reason smart pointers are useful. You may want to add that they make dynamic memory allocation easier to manage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting a lot of down votes for answering your question that is in the comment and not in the title. In the comment, you ask `However, is it a better idea if I create the parameter on the stack rather on the heap.` This is the answer for that question:

Automatic variables should always be preferred, but it has it is limitation. A reason why you might want to allocate memory dynamically that only lasts for the scope is when you want to create a large memory, the stack has a limited size and so you might want to create it on the heap if it might breach that size.

Comment: That's the point of dynamic allocation. malloc/free and new/delete serve the same goal. And std::vector<> as well. So, How does this answer the question?

Comment: @sehe Not sure what you are asking, this is exactly what I'm trying to say.

Comment: That's far removed from the real merit of said smart pointers. The point is to make memory management automatic and less error prone.

Comment: @sehe I don't deny that, OP is asking why he might do this vs that. I gave him a reason. It doesn't take away anything from smart pointers.

Comment: Ok. I think the wording is still pretty unclear/unfortunate. But with the clarification, I've undownvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `auto_ptr`. It is obsolete now, because of its unusual copy semantics. If you would like to have real `smart pointers`, use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`.

Now, your question is: why use `unique_ptr` ? When you create an object `A` inside an object `B`, you could declare it  as an attribute of `B` class, for example. It is on the stack, and you don't need `unique_ptr`. This is true, but sometimes, your object `B` must be initialized *without* the instance of `A`, because, for example, `A` is too big, or you don't use it. Thus, you must do dynamic allocation, and it helps to use  `unique_ptr` to not avoid to `delete` your pointer.

Comment: Actually, `unique_ptr` helps you **not** avoid to `delete` your pointer... :)

Comment: Of course, that should be "not forget"... I thought that was obvious

Answer (score 0):

```
Consider you have:

class A { };
class B : public A { };

A* factory(bool willBeA)
{
  return willBeA ? new A() : new B();
}

int main()
{
  //I want to get an instance of A or maybe B depending on a value
  bool val = false;
  unique_ptr<A> ptr { factory(val) }; //you need having a pointer to the returned value of A

  //do something

  //no need for delete

  return 0;
}
```

In this case, you cannot create an automatic variable to store A, because you actually do not know if an instance of A or B will be used.